# Two UI updates at same time

Tags: android, user-interface, ui-thread

Hi am trying to build an UI like Plus news ,

First try : 
i tried to use ListView as a vertical view and every News feed is a horizontal ListView
but the problem was "row reusing" , the list view reuse views and this make my application slow ,

Second Try : 
i built a custom ui using lots of layouts , main scrollview with horizontal scrollview , 
after the view built it's extremely smooth but the problem was that the ui takes 10-30 seconds to be built , and the activity be in a dark view until the building process done ,

so it's ok for me , but i need to show dialog saying "Loading Ui" , but i can't show it , 
becase the building process the being processed in the main thread , and also the dialog will be show in the main thread ,

so how to achieve  that ?!

i tried to use handlers , threads , but i got the Looper.prepare error

thanks

---

Update :

My problem with listview is :

every time i scroll the new rows shown as if  the first time , so what , i am using a lazy loading image with a progressbar , every time the row show the progressbar shown and wait until load images from sd ,  it takes 1 second but the problem is 1 second for 100 image is 100 second,

so if this 100 secs  is taken for only one time so then all scrollers will work smoothly , so if there is any way to stop resusing the convertedView this will be the solution - i used this solution in iphone and it worked -

Comment: What you should use is Async Task Class. Anyway, like a.ch said, ListView is a better option. WHat happens when you try and load lots of layouts.. with unknown amounts of images.. You will hit Memory issues, and very slow performance. ListView loads on the fly, as is needed, keeping memory down, and initialisation time. But yea, each time you scroll it needs to load in the new items. Consider making this area faster.

Comment: Totally agree with you, except for one thing: `AsyncTask` won't do here, because the major load in @Yahia "Second Try" happens on inflating view hierarchy, which cannot be run on background thread.

Comment: i have no problem with memory,  my images are small 1 kb , but the problem is the process of opening the image from sd this is the 1 sec delay

Answer (score 1):

You may try to show spinner in your `onCreate(..)` before calling `setContentView(..)`, but that's won't be a nice solution, since you may encounter other problems, such as OOM on different devices.

I would recommend you to give `ListView` second chance, it's a very nice widget, but you need to use it properly. And "row reusing" makes it faster, actually, when used properly (not inflating new View every time [`getView(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) is called, making use of ViewHolder-pattern).